# How do you change systems-wide keyboard short cuts on the commandline? (e.g. shift-ctrol-e = Emoji on Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

In Uubuntu 19.04, shift-ctrl-e seems to be bound to Emoji (System wide). However, this clashes with other kdb shortcuts, e.g. in Google docs.

How do I change this keyboard shortcut? Note that it isn't listed in the settings app (at least not alongside the other system-wide keyboard shortcuts).

More generally: Where in the file system / user directory are the system-wide keyboard shortcuts stored (including the ones that you access via the settings app).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161021/how-do-you-change-the-shift-ctrl-e-emoji-shortcut

Comment: Yeah, I asked that question over on askubuntu too. Sadly no answers yet.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut can be changed in ibus-setup. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039008/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-emoji-picker/1039039#1039039